# Discord bot player state randomly changing to idle and therefore stopping playback in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

`I know this has been asked before, under different titles. But yet none of the questions could answer my specific problem`

Okay, so this is a stupid problem. My discord.js bot randomly leaves the voice channel before the track is finished, I suppose that this is because the `AudioPlayerStatus.Idle` event is fired early because I only had this line:

```js
connection.state.status != "destroyed" ? connection.destroy() : null
```

inside the `player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {})` event.

I also made two more event listeners for the player to see what else might be the problem:

```js
player.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error)
    interaction.editReply({
        embeds: [{
            title: "An unexpected error has occurred",
            color: 0xF03C3C,
            description: `Error: ${error.message}`,
        }]
    })
}); player.on("debug", (info) => {
    console.log(info)
});
```

No errors were outputted to the console. But I got these two logs:

```bash
state change:
from {"status":"buffering","resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"playing","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":0,"resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}

state change:
from {"status":"playing","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":129400,"resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"idle","resource":false,"stepTimeout":false}
```

I'm not sure what will actually cause it to switch to Idle only after 2 minutes of playback (`129400` milliseconds)

I just thought of a potential fix while writing this, and that is to compare `playbackDuration` with the actual track's duration, except that I don't know how to get the duration of an audio resource.

Here's my full code:

```js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    ChatInputCommandInteraction,
    ActionRowBuilder,
    ButtonBuilder,
    ButtonStyle
} = require('discord.js');
const {
    embedColor
} = require("../../envConfig");
const quran = require('../../tools/quran');
const { createAudioPlayer, NoSubscriberBehavior, createAudioResource, joinVoiceChannel, AudioPlayerStatus } = require("@discordjs/voice")

module.exports = {
    data: /* Slash Command */,
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply({
            ephemeral: interaction.options.get("private") ? interaction.options.get("private").value : false
        })

        let surah = interaction.options.getInteger("surah")
        let reader = interaction.options.getString("reader") || "ar.ahmedalajmi"
        let audioUrl = `https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio-surah/128/${reader}/${surah}.mp3`
        
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) {
            interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [{
                    title: "Couldn't play surah",
                    color: 0xF03C3C,
                    description: "You are not in a voice channel! Please join <#1204055881101348965> first",
                }]
            })
            return
        }
        if (interaction.member.voice.channel.id !== "1204055881101348965") {
            interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [{
                    title: "Couldn't play surah",
                    color: 0xF03C3C,
                    description: "You are not in <#1204055881101348965>!",
                }]
            })
            return
        }

        const player = createAudioPlayer()
        let connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: "1204055881101348965",
            guildId: interaction.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            debug: true,
            selfDeaf: false,
            selfMute: false
        })
        connection.subscribe(player)
        //interaction.guild.members.me.voice.setDeaf(false)
        //interaction.guild.members.me.voice.setMute(false)

        let resource = createAudioResource(audioUrl, {
            metadata: {
                title: `Surah ${(quran.surahs[surah - 1]).split(".")[1].trim()}`
            }
        })
        player.play(resource)

        //* Buttons
        let row = new ActionRowBuilder();
        let stopButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId("stopQuran-" + interaction.user.id)
            .setEmoji("⛔")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);
        let restartButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId("restartQuran-" + interaction.user.id)
            .setEmoji("")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);
        let pauseButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId("pauseQuran-" + interaction.user.id)
            .setEmoji("⏸")
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);
        row.addComponents(stopButton, pauseButton, restartButton)

        
        player.on("stateChange", (oldState, newState) => {
            console.log(oldState.status, newState.status)
            if (oldState.status !== "playing" && newState.status === "playing") {
                interaction.editReply({
                    embeds: [{
                        title: `Playing Surah ${(quran.surahs[surah - 1]).split(".")[1].trim()}, Chapter ${surah}`,
                        color: parseInt(embedColor),
                        description: `By ${quran.readerChoiceNames[reader]}`
                    }],
                    components: [row]
                })
            }
        })

        player.on("error", (error) => {
            console.error(error)
            interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [{
                    title: "An unexpected error has occurred",
                    color: 0xF03C3C,
                    description: `Error: ${error.message}`,
                }]
            })
        }); player.on("debug", (info) => {
            console.log(info)
        });

        player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, (oldState, newState) => {
            
            //console.log(oldState.status, newState.status)
            let newRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            let newStopButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("stopQuran-" + interaction.user.id)
                .setEmoji("⛔")
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
                .setDisabled(true);
            let newRestartButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("restartQuran-" + interaction.user.id)
                .setEmoji("")
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                .setDisabled(true);
            let newPauseButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("pauseQuran-" + interaction.user.id)
                .setEmoji("⏸")
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                .setDisabled(true);
            newRow.addComponents(newStopButton, newPauseButton, newRestartButton)

            interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [{
                    title: `Finished Playing Surah ${(quran.surahs[surah - 1]).split(".")[1].trim()}, Chapter ${surah}`,
                    color: parseInt(embedColor),
                    description: `By ${quran.readerChoiceNames[reader]}`
                }],
                components: [newRow]
            })
            connection.state.status != "destroyed" ? connection.destroy() : null
        })
    }
};
```

This doesn't seem to work as expected at all. Any help would be appreciated :D